# Regexp equivalent of str.getSubstring(x, y);

Tags: java, javascript, regex, parsing

What would be a RegExp equivalent of substring from position `x` to position `y`?

For example:

```
0001..STACK.OVERFLOW...IS.AWESOME.13052011
```

I know that the value of a field called `'status'` in this fixed length string is 8 characters starting from position 26. What would a regex in JavaScript (and Java) look like to get the `"AWESOME"` string?

I'm trying to build a parser of mainframe screens that come over JMS as fixed length strings. And the idea is to write a UI where a user could highlight a section of a string, fill the 'field name' field, select type (int, String..) and have a Java class generated automatically.

Comment: Want it to be as flexible and generic as possible. What if I don't know the exact position of the field but I know that it's preceded by 'STATUS: [' and fllowed by "]". Regexp could get that.. something like (?<=STATUS: [).*(?=]) may be...

Comment: Given that all 4 answers so far presumed you were being quite literal about starting at index 26, I'd have to say your question was very poorly specified.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry about that - first time on stack overflow.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.{26}(.{8})
```

The first .{26} eats the first 26 characters no matter what they are. The (.{8}) captures the next 8 characters and stores them. For Javascript you can use

```
var matches= /.{26}(.{8})/.exec("0001..STACK.OVERFLOW...IS.AWESOME.13052011")
```

and matches[1] will be the substr that you're looking for. (matches[0] always contains the entire matched string)

note that the .s can be replaced by character classes if you want (ex. [\w]{26}[\w]{8})

Comment: Hehe, this was the first thing I've tried too but it includes the first 26 characters: "0001..STACK.OVERFLOW...IS.AWESOME."

Comment: That's because you're looking in matches[0] which always contains the entire matched string. You should use matches[1] instead, which will contain the matches from the first capture group.

Comment: Cool, can you mark it as the accepted answer? I'm new to this place, do you do that or does it just get marked that way after some number of up votes?

Comment: Looks like it's that green tick symbol which I could just click. Is there a competition on who gets most accepted answers?

Comment: I dunno dude, but there is so much positive reinforcement from badges and reputation and whatnots and whoozits. I mean who could resist answering questions?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=.{26}).{8}")` should do it, and the substring is the matched text.

You can't do it in javascript because JavaScript regexs don't support lookbehind, but you can do a capturing group.
In JavaScript the closest you can get is `/^[\s\S]{26}([\s\S]{8})/`, and the substring is in group 1.

Note, that this counts chars, not codepoints, so might split a surrogate pair, but JavaScript and Java's built in `substring` functions have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Tried this one and it returns "0001..STACK.OVERFLOW...IS.AWESOME.". Any way to make the ^[\s\S]{26} part non capturing?

Comment: Not in JavaScript, no, there is no way to make it non-capturing.  If you know the total length, then you can index backwards though because javascript supports lookahead even though it doesn't support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
^(?<=.{28}).{8}
```

This will *not* work in JavaScript because JavaScript does not support look-behind.

Edit (regarding newlines): if you want the `.` to match new lines, you have to specify `Pattern.DOTALL` in Java. For more detail, look at [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in JavaDocs, particularly `Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags)`.

You can also turn this on by including `(?s)` in your regex.

Another thought: if, instead of strictly getting the substring starting 28 characters in, you want to get one that follows some other pattern (like 8 characters after "STATUS"), you could just do this:

```
^(?s)(?<=STATUS).{8}
```

Comment: This won't work when the string contains newlines in or before the matched portion since `.` without the `s` modifier does not match newlines.

Comment: Good point. I think in Java you can also use the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Yep.  You can pass that to compile, or if you want to use it with one of the methods on `String`, you can put `(?s)` at the front of your pattern, or wrap the bit that uses `.` in `(?s:...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `^(?<=.{2}).*(?=.{3})$` will give you substring starting after  2 and ending 3 position before. And yeah, this doesn't work with JS, but even if it did, stick with substring.

Comment: Yes but I need it to work in JS too.. won't this return 'AWESOME.13052' though?

Comment: I am not giving exact regex. Change 2 and 3 as desired.